# Should speed/cache settings go into the virtual host file or the apache config?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, virtual-host

Some CMS's or websites don't seem to like all the speed settings we use so we've been putting the following into each virtual host file:

```
# SPEED SETTINGS
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Expired headers on cached items - file types below will be cached
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 90 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

# Which file types to compress (deflate in Apche speak)
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/xml application/x-javascript application/javascript

# The downside of mod_deflate is the CPU time consumption so you may have to lower the compression level depending on your server
# UNCOMMENT and change number - 9 being the highest compression level, standard is 6
# DeflateCompressionLevel 6

# Deactivate compression for buggy browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Tells proxies not to deliver the same content to all user agents, because some of them just can't handle it
Header append Vary User-Agent

# Saves time on every request by turning off - can effect cgi scripts so comment out if having issues
HostnameLookups Off

# Persistent connections let the browsers request multiple files with one TCP connection, thus reducing overhead for TCP handshakes and speeding up requests a lot
KeepAlive On

# The maximum number of requests per one persistent connection - bad spambots may suck up all available connections if number is too high
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

# The timeout after which a persistent connection is dropped - if high peaks in traffic are expected, don't set too high as you might have no connections left to serve new incoming requests
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

But we've been told they should be set globally in the apache config for the server - are there any downsides to controlling the settings host-by-host?

Comment: Please cite the source of this information!

Comment: Our hosting provider said it wasn't a good idea.